# How can I make a timer to take step by step instead of progressbar.value

Tags: vb.net

Alright so this might be slightly hard to explain very well, but here we go.

**Intro:**

I'm counting files in 9 channels. Each channel is basically a path (Like \server\share\folder). Right now I have a timer and progressbar. When `progressbar.value = 10`, `channel 1` is being searched. `When progressbar.value = 20`, `channel 2` is being searched (by searched i the files within the specified path is being counted). And so on all the way to value 100. At value 100 it will loop back to value 1 and start over.

The issue with this that some of the paths that are in the channels have a huge amout of files, so it will take some time before its done and it seems to make the program laggy when it hits that progressbar.value that the channel with many files is hooked to.

**What I'm looking for:**

So I don't want a timer that counts based on its interval and then everything depend on that. I want to count the channel, then when its complete I want to move on to the next channel. Basically like this: `Channel 1, counting, complete, moving to channel 2.` `Channel 2, counting, complete, moving to channel 3.` So on... But it have to be accurate and controlled. So each channel should use say **minimum** one second.

Yes, I don't want it to constantly count. It should count each channel till complete, but if complete in very short time (say for example 5 millisecond)- still wait a second or so and then continue to next channel. To accomplish this I've tried a few things, but none works like I want. See further down.

---

Here it the counter which is within `timermain.tick`

```
pbMain.Increment(1)
                                     'Channel 1
     If cbc1.Checked = True Then
        If pbMain.Value = 10 Then
            Try
                Dim fileTotal As Integer
                For Each item As String In lbChannel1.Items
                    fileTotal += My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(item.ToString, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, (tbExt1.Text)).Count
                Next
                tbCount1.Text = String.Format("{0}", fileTotal.ToString)
            Catch ex As Exception
                lbErrors.Items.Add(String.Concat(TimeOfDay & " Error 001: ", ex.Message)) 'Error output

            End Try
            Dim tCount As Integer = 0
        End If
    End If
                                      'Channel 2
    '... same as above. Then channel 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9...
```

You'll notice the `pbmain.value = 10 then` which is the progressbar I've been talking about. And`lbchannel1.items`is the channel which is a listbox with paths as items. This repeats for all the 9 channels, but the others is at pbmain.value 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 and 90 while the one in my code above is at value 10.

**The Question:**

How can I do this but not use progressbar.value as a way of activating the counting for the channels? It's not very accurate.

After the question posted I've `tried performstep` and `thread.sleep` ++. Have a look at the updates.

*PS: I don't need a progressbar. Its not there for visual effects.*

---

**Update #1:**

Instead of `pbmain.increment(1)` I tried to add a `pbmain.performstep()` between each channel so it counts and when thats complete it skips to next channel and counts. Could work, but its not controlled at all and with that it loops like crazy. So this, but controlled somehow would be great. It should not use milliseconds between each channel, but rather a second or so. The application is  supposed to count controlled, not constantly.

**Update #2:**

Got a tips from Plutonix in comments to try `progressbar Marquee` mode which I'm currently trying.

**Update #3:**

I tried Thread.sleep between each count, but it seems to freeze the program really badly.

Comment: You arent going to be able to accurately increment a progressbar using a for each loop.  Have you tried the ProgressBar in Marquee mode?

Comment: Hmm no, I haven't even heard of that. I'll do some research on that.

Comment: When you say `I have hidden progressbar`, does that mean that the progressbar is not shown ? if it's not visible, what's the point of putting a progressbar ?

Comment: @Martin I must admit I'm not sure. In the beginning I wanted to see how the timer was doing through the progressbar for debugging purposes, but in the end I guess I never thought of figuring out another way to do it. I don't need the progressbar. Would it be possible to do something similar to "`if timer.tick = 10 then`" instead?

Comment: You can just use a variable `CurrentChannel` that will hold the channel being analyzed, and when done you increment it be one...

Comment: @Martin Sounds like that could be something. Not sure how to set this up tho. But if say the folders are empty, will this loop like crazy? - it should not loop counting like crazy, but each channel should minimum say use one second in counting no matter how many files it counts. Like this: `If time-used is less than for example one second, still wait that one second before next channel. Else if time-used is greater than one second, finish the counting then continue to next channel.`

Comment: I think the End of Statement expected error is because you don't need the very last ) on that line.

    CType(Controls("lbChannel" & Channel), ListBox).Items.Count > 0 Then

Comment: Spot on, @GarethOates. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this, see comments inside code...

```
Private Sub CheckChannels()
  'We will run through each Channel
  For Channel = 1 to 9
    Dim Cbox = CType(Controls.Find("cbc" & Channel, True).FirstorDefault(), CheckBox)
    'That will work if the 9 checkboxes names are cbcX
    If Cbox.Checked = True Then
      Try
        Dim fileTotal As Integer
        'If we have files in the ListBox
        'Again, the listboxes names must be lbChannelX
        If CType(Controls.find(("lbChannel" & Channel), True).FirstorDefault(), ListBox).Items.Count > 0 Then
          'We run through each item in ListBox
          For Each item As String In CType(Controls.Find("lbChannel" & Channel, True).FirstorDefault(), ListBox).Items
            'We count the files
            fileTotal += My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(item.ToString, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, (CType(Controls.Find("tbExt" & Channel, True).FirstorDefault(), TextBox).Text)).Count
          Next
          'We update the count for that channel
          CType(Controls.Find("tbCount" & Channel, True).FirstorDefault(), TextBox).Text = String.Format("{0}", fileTotal.ToString)
        Else
          'We have no files in that channel, we can do Thread.Sleep(1000)
        End If
      Catch ex As Exception
        'Error output
        lbErrors.Items.Add(String.Concat(TimeOfDay & " Error 00" & Channel & " : ", ex.Message)) 
      End Try
      'I don't know what's the use of this var
      Dim tCount As Integer = 0
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Martin, this is great. I did not know the usage of ctype either. I'm going to test it throughout the day. Just copied it into the code and I get two probably simple errors. **1)** Missing a next on the For Channel = 1 to 9 and **2)** on the second `If CType` (for lbchannel). Just that its missing an end-statement. Just to be sure, where would I put the `end if` and `next` thats missing? Also, the "dim tCount" is for something else further down in the code. Don't mind that. :)

Comment: @MadsTheMan Corrected, just replace the last `End If` by `Next`

Comment: For some weird reason I still get error on `If CType(Controls("lbChannel" & Channel), ListBox).Items.Count > 0) Then` this line. The error points at `0)` saying "End of statement expected.". It looks like the` For Each` after that starting over at the "for channel". Not sure how to explain it, but I'll update my answer, have a look there.

Comment: @MadsTheMan remove the parenthesis after `> 0`

Comment: So I just ran my first attempt and I get an error at the first if-statement saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. All my checkboxes have the name cbc1-9 and same goes for the listboxes lbchannel1-9. Though they are placed in tabcontrol's, could this cause this issue?

Comment: I replaced `Controls('Name')` by `Control.Find('Name', True).FirstorDefault()`

Comment: It works, in a way. It seems to be counting wrong tho. I'm not quite sure how it happens, but it seems to be adding up the numbers in tbcount.text. So if say the folders in channel 1-4 have 10 files each and the rest of the 6 channels have no files. Then tbcount1 = 10, tbcount2 = 20, tbcount3 = 30 tbcount4 = 40, while they all should have =10.  Tbcount 5-9 will have =40. Any ideas why this happens?